# dropping multiple tables ending with "1617"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to drop multiple tables ending with the string "1617"

I have come across massive procedures to do this but is there an easy way

My tables look like mytable1617 and I have loads of them

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += '
DROP TABLE ' 
    + QUOTENAME(s.name)
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';'
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
    WHERE t.name LIKE '1617%';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
WHERE t.name LIKE '1617%';
```

is looking for tables *starting* with `1617`. You wanted:

```
WHERE t.name LIKE '%1617';
```

Comment: I marked this as my answer as the script worked, but when I look at the DB all the tables are still there. Even though the script printed DROP TABLE [dbo].[mytable1617]

Answer (score 1):

Just change the search pattern

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @sql += '
    DROP TABLE ' 
        + QUOTENAME(s.name)
        + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';'
        FROM sys.tables AS t
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
        ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
        WHERE t.name LIKE '%1617'; --tables ending with 1617

    PRINT @sql;
```

Comment: I use getting errors related to foreign keys so I think I might need to delete the tables in the right order?

Comment: @user2786484 of course, if there are dependencies, they need to be deleted in the correct order or the dependencies removed.

Comment: you can find the foreign keys like this `select * from sys.foreign_keys WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('tablename')`

Comment: Didnt find any thats odd

Comment: Did you just copy and paste that SQL in the comment? Did you replace `('tablename')` with your table name?